# file changes not being saved

Tags: files

I'm new to Linux so please be gentle :-)

I'm trying to update a `.dtl` file that contains `html` for the helpdesk application `otrs` that I'm running.  I made a copy of the `.dtl` file and moved it over to a windows share so I could manipulate the file easier in an `html` editor which is all good.  The required changes have been made and can see the changes saved when I open it again in the `html` editor.  The problem occurs when I copy the updated file back onto the server, it doesn't retain my changes.

Can anybody shed any light on why this is happening please?

Comment: How do you copy the file from windows share to server, i mean which command are you using and where do you copy the file (location in server)? Does that location where you are copying the file contain the old file with the same name? And which linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Linux, you have seen the light :)

I think it would be easier to edit directly on the server.
You could do something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nano -y --force-yes
sudo nano <path>
```

Where path is the full path of the file you want to edit.

---

If you have to edit on Windows for whatever reason, FileZilla works good: https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: nano comes to ubuntu by default, and opening file with sudo will change ownership of that file to root.

Comment: @Serg on my ubuntu server I spinned up a few days ago, it didn't come installed. As for ownership, what do you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for the info guys :-) the reason I was trying to do modifications in windows was so I can preview as I go along and because I'm more comfortable in the windows environment so thought it would be quicker.  I'll take a look at nano and I've also done some editing with vi so should get the job done.  As a matter of interest, can I preview this file without making it live?

Comment: @Elaina what do you mean preview it?

Comment: I've made some changes to the html in the file but can't see if the layout is correct in the browser without overwriting the live file.

Comment: @Elaina you could save a backup copy before starting:
`cp original copyname`